# How can give CSS for Javascript Error Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JHHTw/)**

I am working in **Javascript** Validation. I want to give Separate colour for the text 
**" Please enter Valid Email ID "**

When User Enter a `wrong email id` and press, there is one Error message will come. I want give red colour for this Error message. Only for this Error message i need red colour

**HTML**

```
<label id="message">We don't Spam. Promise</label> <br />
<input autocomplete="on" type="text"  name="booking_email" onkeyup="validate()"   id="SignupText" class="InputSignup" placeholder="Enter Your Email" /> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="subButton"  onclick="submitEmail();"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function validate()
{
var booking_email = $('input[name=booking_email]').val();

if(booking_email == '' ){
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="We don't Spam. Promise";
}else if( /(.+)@(.+){1,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(booking_email) )
{
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Your email is valid"
  if(event.which == 13){
    submitEmail();
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Type your email id";

  if(event.which == 13){
    submitEmail();
  }
}
}
function submitEmail()
{
var booking_email = $('input[name=booking_email]').val();
if(booking_email=="")
{

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please enter Your Email ID"
}
else if( /(.+)@(.+){1,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(booking_email) )

{
alert('success');

}

else {document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please enter Valid Email ID";}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please enter Your Email ID"
```

to

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Please enter Your Email ID</span>";
```

wrapping the text with a span that has the color set to red ?

Answer (score 1):

I created a <kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHHTw/2/)</kbd>

I wrapped a `<span class='red'></span>` around the text and then created a class `.red` in the css.

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<span class='red'>Please enter Your Email ID</span>";
```

CSS

```
.red{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you print an error message you could wrap it in a `div` with a class or `error-message`

```
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="<div class='error-message'>Please enter Valid Email ID</div>";
```

Then in your CSS file you can do

```
.error-message
{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

css:

```
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

and:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<span class='error'>Please enter Your Email ID</span>";
```

Other option would be to keep separate div for your errors and change its visibility and or text accordingly.

However, ultimate solution would be just to use correct input type.

```
<input type="email" name="email">
```

it works best as cross-device and it has error handling build in using regexp, so you can get away using those nasty javascript codes :) read more:

http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/

Answer (score 1):

friend try this code.. i have used jquery css method which makes solution very easier.you don't need to create class and div for message.You just need to follow below code. I have used jquery css method and I have used it only in success message,but you can use it for all.Just follow the syntax.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validate()
{
var booking_email = $('input[name=booking_email]').val();

if(booking_email == '' ){
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="We don't Spam. Promise";
}else if( /(.+)@(.+){1,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(booking_email) )
{
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Your email is valid"
 $('#message').css("color","red");
  $('#message').css("font-weight","bold");

  if(event.which == 13){
    submitEmail();
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Type your email id";

  if(event.which == 13){
    submitEmail();
  }
}
}
function submitEmail()
{
var booking_email = $('input[name=booking_email]').val();
if(booking_email=="")
{

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please enter Your Email ID"
}
else if( /(.+)@(.+){1,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(booking_email) )

{
alert('success');

}

else {document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please enter Valid Email ID";}


}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<label id="message">We don't Spam. Promise</label> <br />
<input autocomplete="on" type="text"  name="booking_email" onkeyup="validate()"   id="SignupText" class="InputSignup" placeholder="Enter Your Email" /> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="subButton"  onclick="submitEmail();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

here is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/JHHTw/3/

Comment: thnaks for help....i already got answer. and i dont want to give color for all messages. Only Single messgae i need to give color

Comment: @Deekey you can set any property,not only color.I have taken bold and color.You can take any of the property.